# Set three divs on one line from PHP foreach

Tags: php, html

My PHP script's foreach cycle generates a div elements (product info and image width is 270px) into a bigger div (width 900px). And every new product info div is on new line but i want to have 2 or 3 div element on a one line. So if i have 8 products they should be on 3 or 4 lines, now i have these on 8 lines...

How to do it?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from all solutions one more way to achieve this. if you are looking 
solutions from foreach loop. you can break array by using [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

```
<?php

$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
// It will chunk array into 3,3 values.
$newArray = array_chunk($array, 3, true);

foreach ($newArray as $value) {

    echo '<div class="separator">';
    // Iterate inner arrays. 
    foreach ($value as $innerValue) {
        echo $innerValue . ',';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

**Output:-** Now inside separator div , 3 div will be displayed.

```
<div class="separator">1,2,3,</div>
<div class="separator">4,5,6,</div>
<div class="separator">7,8,9,</div>
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](https://eval.in/102585)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this ? for example you want three divs per line then wrap every three item in a wrapper div and float all the items to left and end every wrapper with a clear div :

```
$ct = 1;
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
  if($ct%3==0) echo '<div class="wrapper">'; //start wrapper div
  echo '<div style="float:left">'.$val.'</div>';
  if($ct%3==0){
    echo '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
    echo '</div>'; //close wrapper div
  } 
  $ct++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to all be on one line, you should really use `<span>` instead of `<div>`  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div

> There are multiple differences between div and span. The most notable
>   difference is how the elements are displayed. In standard HTML, a div
>   is a block-level element whereas a span is an inline element.

Or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

> `<span>` is very much like a `<div>` element, but `<div>` is a block-level element whereas
>   a `<span>` is an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

you should use wrapper

```
echo '<div style="display: table" id="wraper">';
foreach($some as $key => $value){
  // here you generate your divs for example:
  echo '<div style="display: table-cell"></div>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

or you can use float css param on divs in foreach, when divs doesn`t have space in outer content they will drop to new line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap then they have css for that in it otherwise this code will work for you

```
$count=0;
foreach (array_expression as $value)
{
  if(count!=2)
  {
    <div style="float: left; margin: 0 20px 5px 0;">
      <div> // create your div here
      </div>
    </div>
    count++;
  }
  else
  {
    <div> // 3rd div
    </div>
    count=0;
  }
}
```